# This is the title to modify hosts file to not resolve

Tags: linux, unix, url, dns, hosts

I understand that say putting in the following:

`127.0.0.1 some.machine.com`

into a hosts file will force some.machine.com resolve locally.

What if I do not want a specific url not to resolve at all? say "dev/null"

Comment: To prevent accessing an outbound url request is with firewall iptables...
Did not see this immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same logic to negate an URL from resolving which you actually did allow to resolve.
For example, I blocked

> www.TechBeamers.com

Update the host file with the following entry:

> 1.1.1.1 www.TechBeamers.com

Before updating the host file:

```
Pinging www.TechBeamers.com [xyz.xx.yy.xyz] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from xyz.xx.yy.xyz: bytes=32 time=304ms TTL=50
Reply from xyz.xx.yy.xyz: bytes=32 time=293ms TTL=50
```

Post updating the host file:

```
Pinging www.TechBeamers.com [1.1.1.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

Comment: 1.1.1.1 vs 0.0.0.0  ?

Comment: ip-address "0.0.0.0" used in the case when you want to point to default gateway or specify the default route for packets. it cannot be used as a normal IP address. And "1.1.1.1" is just a normal public IP address.